# GAE dev_appserver "No module named lxml"

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, lxml

It seems lxml is not available for me in dev_appserver. I have test project is `import lxml` line built with windows python sdk 1.6.6. "No module named lxml". I assume something with installed version of python, but I have Python 2.7.

```
import webapp2
import lxml

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write('Hello world!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)],
                              debug=True)
```

===

```
application: teslxml
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.1"
- name: lxml
  version: latest
```

==

```
dev_appserver.py teslxml
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update: This isn't true anymore, lxml is now shipped out of the box. 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27

---

lxml doesn't come out of the box with Google App Engine, you need to [install it](http://lxml.de/installation.html).

Comment: WOW, didn't know that, I thought there special version from google

Comment: I think they can't bind with the setup because of licensing issues.

Comment: It's not the licensing, it's the problem of having binary files in the SDK (or requiring compilation during the install).

Comment: but where is the python environment of the google app engine ??? where should i install it?

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting the 'no module named lxml' error, but was unable to install the module separately and I resolved this by telling pip to install with a specific version number, like so;

> pip install lxml==[versionnumber]